# Change purrr reduce column naming to numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyverse, purrr

When using `purrr::reduce()` to left join a large list of data frames the default is to names the columns with .x, .y, .x.x, .y.y etc..

Is it possible to change this behaviour to obtain column names with numeric endings? e.g.

.1, .2, .3, .4 ?

```
# test data
data.frame(id= rep(letters[1:5],3,20), visits = rep(1:4,each=5), data =rep(1:5,3,20)) %>%
  # split df into a list for each visit
  group_split(visits) %>%
  # left join each nhs_joint_side
  reduce(left_join, by = c("id"))


# A tibble: 5 x 9
  id    visits.x data.x visits.y data.y visits.x.x data.x.x visits.y.y data.y.y
  <chr>    <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>      <int>    <int>      <int>    <int>
1 a            1      1        2      1          3        1          4        1
2 b            1      2        2      2          3        2          4        2
3 c            1      3        2      3          3        3          4        3
4 d            1      4        2      4          3        4          4        4
5 e            1      5        2      5          3        5          4        5

# ideal data
# A tibble: 5 x 9
  id    visits_1  data_1  visits_2  data_2 visits_3    data_3    visits_4  data_4
  <chr>    <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>      <int>    <int>      <int>    <int>
1 a            1      1        2      1          3        1          4        1
2 b            1      2        2      2          3        2          4        2
3 c            1      3        2      3          3        3          4        3
4 d            1      4        2      4          3        4          4        4
5 e            1      5        2      5          3        5          4        5
```

Comment: There is a `suffix` argument in `left_join` that you can amend

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, I am not sure that would help as I need sequential naming of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the columns first, and then merge:

```r
df %>%
  group_split(visits) %>%
  imap(function(x, y) x %>% 
         rename_with(~paste(., y, sep = '_'), -id)) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = 'id')
```

output

```r
  id    visits_1 data_1 visits_2 data_2 visits_3 data_3 visits_4 data_4
  <chr>    <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>
1 a            1      1        2      1        3      1        4      1
2 b            1      2        2      2        3      2        4      2
3 c            1      3        2      3        3      3        4      3
4 d            1      4        2      4        3      4        4      4
5 e            1      5        2      5        3      5        4      5
```

data

```r
df <- data.frame(id= rep(letters[1:5],3,20), visits = rep(1:4,each=5), data =rep(1:5,3,20))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I can't quite get my head around this. so imap() uses the values supplied (col names) and innately generates index of each name, which is then used by rename_with?

Comment: `imap` is a shortcut for `map2(x, names(x), ...)`, so here it maps over the lists of dfs and takes the splitted df (x) and its names (y) as arguments. The names is the names of each df in the list (and because they have no names, it's assigned to their index, `1,2,3,4`). Then it does what the function does for each dfs, i.e. rename_with each column, except id, and paste the name of the column (`.`) with the name of the df (`y`).

Comment: Thanks for that